# TikZ, center node between 4 nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

With `tikz` library `calc`, it is possible to center a node between two points:

```
\node (node3) at ($(node1)!0.5!(node2)$) {centered};
```

Whatever is the direction of the line passing through `node1` and `node2`, this makes `node3` *horizontally* centered along this direction.

Is is possible to center instead a node between 4 nodes, when they form a regular shape such as a square, or rectangle, or rhombus? So that the node is **both horizontally and vertically** centered.

Comment: Keep adding : `($($(node1)!0.5!(node2)$)!0.5!($(node3)!0.5!(node4)$)$)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can perhaps use `barycentric cs`:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (-2,2) {1};
\node (b) at (2,2) {2};
\node (c) at (-2,-2) {3};
\node (d) at (2,-2) {4};

\node (e) at (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1) {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain the code `cs:a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1`?

Comment: @toandhsp Section 13.2.2 *Barycentric systems* in the manual. Essentially, the coordinate is defined by a linear combination of the vectors `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` (these are the named coordinates), when all the vectors are weighted equally, you get the center point.